# save value of a fallible table in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

how do i save the value of my fallible table into my database using loop in laravel 5.5.

CONTROLLER:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [

        'student_name'=>'required|max:50|unique:leads,student_name',
        'gender'=>'required|max:50',
        'age'=>'required|max:2',



            ]);

            $leads=new Lead();
            $leads->student_name = $request->student_name;
            $leads->gender = $request->gender;
            $leads->age = $request->age;
            $leads->save();

            //Display a successful message upon save
              return redirect()->route('leads.create')
                  ->with('flash_message', 'Success.');
}
```

CREATE.BLADE

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='student_name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='gender"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='gender'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='age"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='age'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
      if(i>1){
   $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
   i--;
   }
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-12 column">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
     <tr >
      <th class="text-center">
       #
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       StudentName
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Gender
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Age
      </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr id='addr0'>
      <td>
      1
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='student_name'  placeholder='StudentName' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='gender' placeholder='Gender' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='age' placeholder='AGE' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>
```

I want  to save all value in one time is it possible? ...........................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Hmm what exactly are you referring to with "fallible"? All I see is a model `Lead` and no mention of fallible anywhere in the code.

Comment: how to save the value of the table.. try to run the code

Comment: you need to run ajax post, or use form then test it with your $request

Comment: is there simple way? how do i write it on my controller.

Comment: As I can see in your controller, it is good and it can actually save your record, your problem there is the passing of data through request from your blade.

Comment: yeah idnt know how to save if data is multiple then save it all together..

Answer (score 0):

You need to send an array to your controller because at the moment your not posting anything to the controller. Even of you were it would have no idea how much it's recieveing and how to receive it.

For example one request could have student_name1 -> 
student_name20 or it could only have student_name1 -> 
student_name2

If you name the input student_name[]

You can then iterate through the request in your controller, a simple example would be:

```
foreach ($request->student_name as $student){
    Lead::create ([
        'name' => $student
    ]);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: bro this for each is going to be posted in my view?

Comment: No, your logic goes in your controller. You need to post the information from your view to the controller either with a standard form submit e.g. <form route="controllerroute" method="POST"> or post the information using ajax